# SQLite : Select statement from multiple table and merging column

Tags: sqlite

i have another case , i want to merging some column that have a same parent id but different child id each every group,

here is my table1;

```
+---------+----------+
|id_table1| value    | 
+---------+----------+
|   1     | value1   | 
|   2     | value2   | 
|   3     | value3   | 
|   4     | value4   | 
|   5     | value5   |  
|   6     | value6   | 
|   7     | value7   | 
|   8     | value8   |  
|   9     | value9   | 
+---------+----------+
```

table2:

```
+---------+----------+
|id_table1| value    | 
+---------+----------+
|   P1    | valueP1  | 
|   P2    | valueP2  | 
+---------+----------+
```

and this is my relationship table:

```
+---------+----------+---------+
|id_boss  | id_child |  answ   |  
+---------+----------+---------+
|   1     |     2    |    T    |
|   1     |     6    |    F    |
|   2     |     P1   |    T    |
|   2     |     4    |    F    |
|   6     |     P2   |    T    | 
|   6     |     8    |    F    |
+---------+----------+ --------+
```

and i'm looking a way to combine column id_child

and the result would be something like this :

**:: Edited ::**

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|id_boss  | child_T   | child_F   |     
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| value1  |  value2   |  value6   |
| value2  |  valueP1  |  value4   |
| value6  |  valueP2  |  value8   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

id_child first row group id_boss is in child_T
and second row group id_boss is in child_F

Comment: Does every boss have two children? I.e., shouldn't the result column be called `child_T` and `child_F`?

Comment: @cl ignore column answ, i just want to show my whole table,

Comment: Then how is it determined which child goes into column 1 or 2?

Comment: @cl oh, i see, i will follow you're suggestion and use `child_T` and `child_F` column , i will edited my question, please see again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE table1.id_table1 = r1.id_boss) AS id_boss,
       COALESCE( (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE table1.id_table1 = r1.id_child),
                 (SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE table2.id_table2 = r1.id_child)
               ) AS child_T,
       COALESCE( (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE table1.id_table1 = r2.id_child),
                 (SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE table2.id_table2 = r2.id_child)
               ) AS child_F
  FROM r_table AS r1 JOIN r_table AS r2
    ON r1.id_boss = r2.id_boss AND r1.id_child <> r2.id_child AND r1.answ = 'T'
;
```

Test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/32843/2/0)